# Query on clarification about RunLengthEncoding() constructor

Tags: java, oop

For the Part III assignment given in [link](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61bf06/hw/pj1/readme),

## Part III:  Converting an Ocean to a Run-Length Encoding

> write a RunLengthEncoding constructor that takes an Ocean object as its sole parameter and converts it into a run-length encoding of the Ocean.  To accomplish this, you will need to implement a sharkFeeding() method in the Ocean class, which tells you how hungry a given shark is.  Read Ocean.java and RunLengthEncoding.java carefully for an explanation of what methods you must
>   write.
>
> The fields of the Ocean class MUST be private, so the RunLengthEncoding constructor will rely upon the width(), height(), starveTime(), cellContents(), and sharkFeeding() methods.
>
> Testing
>
> Your RunLengthEncoding implementation is required to have a check() method,
>   which walks through the run-length encoding and checks its validity.
>   Specifically, it should print a warning message if any of the following
>   problems are found:
>
> - If two consecutive runs have exactly the same type of contents.
>       For instance, an "F12" run followed by an "F8" run is illegal, because
>       they should have been consolidated into a single run.  (Don't forget,
>       though, that sharks are divided based on how recently they've eaten.)
> - If the sum of all run lengths doesn't equal the size (in cells) of the
>       Ocean; i.e. its width times its height.
>
> You may find that the check() method is very useful in helping to debug your
>   RunLengthEncoding constructors and addFish() and addShark() in Part IV.

here is the incomplete solution:

```
class RunLengthEncoding {

  /**
   *  Define any variables associated with a RunLengthEncoding object here.
   *  These variables MUST be private.
   */

  private DList2 list;
  private long sizeOfRun;
  private int width;
  private int height;
  private static int starveTime;
  /**
   *  The following method is required for Part III.
   */

  /**
   *  RunLengthEncoding() (with one parameter) is a constructor that creates
   *  a run-length encoding of an input Ocean.  You will need to implement
   *  the sharkFeeding method in the Ocean class for this constructor's use.
   *  @param sea is the ocean to encode.
   */

  public RunLengthEncoding(Ocean sea) {
      this.list = new DList2();
      this.width = sea.getWidth();
      this.height = sea.getHeight();
      RunLengthEncoding.starveTime = Ocean.getStarvationTime();

      int index =0;
      int sizeOfTheOcean = sea.getWidth() * sea.getHeight();
      int sameNeighborCount =1;
      TypeAndSize typeAndSizeObject = null;

      while(index < sizeOfTheOcean){
          if(isSameNeighbor(sea,index)){
              sameNeighborCount++;
          }else{
              typeAndSizeObject = sea.cellContents((index/sea.getWidth()), Utility.mod(index, sea.getWidth())).getTypeAndSize(sameNeighborCount);
              this.list.insertFront(typeAndSizeObject.type, typeAndSizeObject.runLength);
              if(typeAndSizeObject.type == Ocean.SHARK){
                  //How do i capture hungerlevel of shark because TypeAndSize only has 2 members
              }
              this.sizeOfRun++;
              sameNeighborCount = 1;
          }
          index++;
      }

      check();
  }


  /**
   * This method checks the type of any two adjacent cells
   * @param sea
   * @param index
   * @return boolean
   */
  private boolean isSameNeighbor(Ocean sea, int index){
      Critter creature1 = sea.cellContents((index/sea.getWidth()), Utility.mod(index, sea.getWidth()));
      Critter creature2 = sea.cellContents(((index+1)/sea.getWidth()), Utility.mod(index+1, sea.getWidth())); 
      if( creature1.equals(creature2) ){
          return true;
      }
      return false;
  }




  /**
   *  check() walks through the run-length encoding and prints an error message
   *  if two consecutive runs have the same contents, or if the sum of all run
   *  lengths does not equal the number of cells in the ocean.
   */

  public void check() {
      DListNode2 node = this.list.sentinel.next;
      int sumOfAllRunLengths = 0;

      while(node != this.list.sentinel){
          if(node.runObject.type == node.next.runObject.type){
              System.out.println("Error message - Two consecutive runs have the same contents\n");
              return;
          }else{
              node = node.next;
          }
      }

      node = this.list.sentinel.next;
      while(node != this.list.sentinel){
          sumOfAllRunLengths += node.runObject.runLength;
          node = node.next;
      }

      if(sumOfAllRunLengths != this.width*this.height){
          System.out.println("Error Message");
      }
  }

}
```

===========================

```
/* Critter.java */

package Project1;
/**
 * The abstract class Critter defines a base class for any creature 
 * that can exist at a specific location in the ocean.
 * @author mohet01
 *
 */
abstract class Critter  {

    /**
     * Below data member defines a location of a Critter in an Ocean
     */

    Point location;


    public Critter(int x, int y){
        location = new Point(x,y);
    }

    public Point getLocation(){
        return location;
    }


    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        return true;
    }



    public abstract TypeAndSize getTypeAndSize(int sameNeighborCount);


    /**
     * This method computes the behavior of the Critter in the Ocean. 
     * Computes new value of location property of Critter.
     * No operation is performed as this is a base class.
     */
    public abstract Critter update(Ocean currentTimeStepSea);


}
```

=======================

```
/* Shark.java */

package Project1;

/**
 * The Shark class defines behavior of a Shark in an Ocean.
 * @author mohet01
 *
 */
class Shark extends Critter{



    /**
     * Below data member specifies the hunger of each shark you add to the 
     * ocean.
     */
    private int hungerLevel;  


    /**
     * Constructor will create a new location for Shark
     * @param x
     *          is the x-coordinate of location(which can be EMPTY) of Shark
     * @param y
     *          is the y-coordinate of location(which can be EMPTY) of Shark
     */
    public Shark(int x, int y, int hungerLevel){
        super(x,y);
        //Sharks are well-fed at birth
        this.hungerLevel = hungerLevel;
    }


    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        if(this.hungerLevel != ((Shark)obj).hungerLevel)
            return false;
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * This method converts the Ocean object of a cell to TypeAndSize object.
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public TypeAndSize getTypeAndSize(int sameNeighborCount){
        TypeAndSize object = new TypeAndSize(Ocean.SHARK, sameNeighborCount);
        return object;
    }
    /**
     *  The following method is required for Part III.
     */

    /**
     *  sharkFeeding() returns an integer that indicates the hunger of the shark
     *  in cell (x, y), using the same "feeding" representation as the parameter
     *  to addShark() described above.  If cell (x, y) does not contain a shark,
     *  then its return value is undefined--that is, anything you want.
     *  Normally, this method should not be called if cell (x, y) does not
     *  contain a shark.  You will need this method to help convert Oceans to
     *  run-length encodings.
     *  @param x is the x-coordinate of the cell whose contents are queried.
     *  @param y is the y-coordinate of the cell whose contents are queried.
     */

    public int sharkFeeding() {
      return this.hungerLevel;
    }

}
```

==============================

```
/* TypeAndSize.java */

/* DO NOT CHANGE THIS FILE. */
/* YOUR SUBMISSION MUST WORK CORRECTLY WITH _OUR_ COPY OF THIS FILE. */

package Project1;

/**
 *  Each TypeAndSize object represents a sequence of identical sharks, fish,
 *  or empty cells.  TypeAndSizes are your way of telling the test program
 *  what runs appear in your run-length encoding.  TypeAndSizes exist solely
 *  so that your program can return two integers at once:  one representing
 *  the type (species) of a run, and the other representing the size of a run.
 *
 *  TypeAndSize objects are not appropriate for representing your run-length
 *  encoding, because they do not represent the degree of hunger of a run of
 *  sharks.
 *
 *  @author Jonathan Shewchuk
 */

class TypeAndSize {

  int type;               // runType EMPTY, SHARK, or FISH
  int runLength;                   // Number of cells in the run for that runType.



/**
   *  Constructor for a TypeAndSize of specified species and run length.
   *  @param species is Ocean.EMPTY, Ocean.SHARK, or Ocean.FISH.
   *  @param runLength is the number of identical cells in this run.
   *  @return the newly constructed Critter.
   */

  TypeAndSize(int species, int runLength) {
    if ((species != Ocean.EMPTY) && (species != Ocean.SHARK) &&
            (species != Ocean.FISH))    {   
      System.out.println("TypeAndSize Error:  Illegal species.");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    if (runLength < 1) {
      System.out.println("TypeAndSize Error:  runLength must be at least 1.");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    this.type = species;
    this.runLength = runLength;

  }

}
```

=============================

```
/* Fish.java */

package Project1;
/**
 * The Fish class defines the behavior of a Fish in an Ocean
 * @author mohet01
 *
 */
class Fish extends Critter{

    /**
     * Constructor will create a new location for Fish
     * @param x
     *          is the x-coordinate of location(which can be EMPTY) of Fish
     * @param y
     *          is the y-coordinate of location(which can be EMPTY) of Fish
     */

    public Fish(int x, int y){
        super(x,y);
    }


    /**
     * This method converts the Ocean object of a cell to TypeAndSize object.
     * 
     */
    public TypeAndSize getTypeAndSize(int sameNeighborCount){
        TypeAndSize object = new TypeAndSize(Ocean.FISH, sameNeighborCount);
        return object;
    }

}
```

==============

Solution is incomplete because, `TypeAnSize` class only holds two members `type` and `runLength`.

Without changing `TypeAndSize` class, I could not understand, how to capture `hungerLevel` of `Shark` in below code of the `RunLengthEncoding` constructor.

```
if(typeAndSizeObject.type == Ocean.SHARK){
  //How do i capture hungerlevel of shark because TypeAndSize only has 2 members
}
```

My question:

Please help me suggest for a solution to capture `hungerLevel` for each `Shark` object with the constraint of not modifying `TypeAndSize` class.

Note: Here is the [link](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61bf06/hw/pj1/) to the skeleton code already provided.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, it's not possible.

But the assignment has noticed this too:

```
*  TypeAndSize objects are not appropriate for representing your run-length
*  encoding, because they do not represent the degree of hunger of a run of
*  sharks.
```

http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61bf06/hw/pj1/TypeAndSize.java

Combine "You may not alter this file" with "it's not appropriate for run-length encoding" makes me think they want you to come up with your own solution.

I guess you'll have to make a workaround for it.

My solution? Well, I'd give `Critter` in your code a method `toRunLengthEncodingSegment`, which returns "." for empty, "F" for fish, "S#" (Where # is hunger) for shark...

And an abstract factory which will build objects from a String like so:

`"."` = Empty
`".2"` = 2 x Empty
`"F.2F"` = Fish, Empty, Empty, Fish
`"S2,2.FS3"` = Shark (hunger 2), Shark (hunger 2), Empty, Fish, Shark (hunger 3)

Like this, you'll be able to convert ocean to Strings and Strings to Oceans. That's the spirit of RunLengthEncoding.

Comment: can't we change the `TypeAndSize` class to accomodate `hungerLevel`. If yes, How do we do that? because i anyways use Dlist as per above code and would like to continue the same.

Comment: @overexchange No, you cannot alter `TypeAndSize`. Such are the rules of the assignment. Alter DList and DListNode to use generics instead.

Comment: i did not get u, by using generics, how would i resolve problem of capturing `hungerLevel` data?

Comment: @overexchange Combine my answer with "Alter Dlist to use generics". You'll be able to have a linked list of `String`, and you'll be able to change `Critters` into `String` and `String` into `Critters`.

Comment: But assignment is recommending to maintain linked list of `TypeAndSize` object in `RunlengthEncoding` class, am i correct?

Comment: @overexchange the assignment is saying you can't use `TypeAndSize` for `RunLengthEncoding`.

Comment: It was no harm to implement these two constructors `public RunLengthEncoding(, , )` & `public RunLengthEncoding(, , , , )` to encode the `Ocean` to `Dlist` of `TypeAndSize` objects which is already implemented, because we did not require hungerLevel info, but the problem is `public Ocean toOcean()` method  decodes `DList` of `TypeAndSize` object back to `Ocean` as per [query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26727357/query-on-clarification-about-toocean-method). Now, How can i my third constructor encode to something other than `TypeAndSize` object? Hope you understand!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64468/discussion-between-pimgd-and-overexchange).